# How is LINQ used in ASP.NET web programming?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am working in my own website project. I am using a DataAdapter to fetch data from a database. How can I use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) instead?

Comment: Hey @Chiranjib, have you used LINQ before or know what it does?

Comment: In your case you could use Linq to DataSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx and Linq to Objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage LINQ in one of the following ways in your case:

- Use [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) if your database is SQL Server
- Use [LINQ to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) if you work with DataSet/DataTable
- Use [LINQ to entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) for a database your accessing via the [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework)
- Use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) at will

Answer (score 0):

To access data using [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL), you need to create a DataContext. Visual Studio has a designer for Data context classes in which you can simply drag and drop tables from the server explorer, or use [SQLMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) to reverse engineer your database. But this only works for SQL Server databases.

For a generic database, you will need to use [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), for which you can generate the Entity class design using [EDM Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx).

If you want to continue using your current approach, you can just call AsEnumerable method on a DataTable in the DataSet, and it will give you an IEnumerable<DataRow>, on which you can use LINQ operators to your heart's content.

Comment: He could also be using his current setup, and then use Linq-to-DataSet against his data sets... there's no absolute need to go to Linq-to-SQL (ORM)